# Spontaneous symmetry breaking without an order operator?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

Spontaneous symmetry breaking occurs when there is a degeneracy in the ground state. Typically it is easiest to determine the degeneracy by finding some operator with a nonzero vacuum expectation value (VEV) that has a nontrivial transformation under the broken symmetry.

As long as it can be shown that the ground state has a degeneracy parameterized by a given set of symmetry generators,  there's no need for an order operator which has a nonzero VEV, correct? I guess my question is, is it *necessary* that some operator obtains a VEV when a symmetry is spontaneously broken?

Comment: What would you have in mind? The generators *Q* with shift the vacuum, $Q|v\rangle\neq 0$, when commuted with absolutely *all* fields still yield vanishing v.e.v.s??

Comment: I'm envisioning a QFT with zero energy and momentum, If this is the case then any field acting on a ground state will also be a ground state (assuming it doesn't annihilate it). This state will transform with respect to whatever representation the field has. In this situation it seems possible for there to be no order operator.